# How to execute custom command or script in Install section of systemd service file?

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I am creating a custom systemd service script that works fine. However I would like to execute a custom script when:

```
sudo systemsctl enable myservice.service
```

is executed.

Is this possible?

Comment: Since 'enabled' entails creation of a symlink, you could use `inotifywait` to listen for the symlink to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in `man systemd.unit`, there is no facility to run custom commands when a service is enabled. There are some possible alternate designs:

- Create a simple bash script that runs the `enable` command on one line and your customer script on the second line.
- Design the other parts of your system that it works when an action is triggered with a service is `started` instead of `enabled`. Directives like `ExecStartPre=` and `ExecSTartPost=` could help with that.

Comment: The install actions essentialy create symlinks, much in the same way that `update-rc.d` manages symlinks to manage what runs at boot using SysV init. What is the use-case for running some other action at `enable`-time as opposed to service `start` time?

Comment: I wanted to do something upon service being enabled to ensure it operates correctly. I realize that can be done as well with customs startup script which is probably what I will have to do anyways.